# How to set and position a background Image in WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, view, wpf-controls, background-image

I need to add an image to my main window background.
Here is what i have

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
        <ImageBrush.Transform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
        </ImageBrush.Transform>

        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/welcome.jpg"/>
        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
    </ImageBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

for some reason, the unused spaces of my background becomes all black with this part of my code
[image]

So i have two questions

1. What causes the background goes all black and how can i fix it?
2. I added the Alignments to my ImageBrush, why isnt the image centered?

Comment: Could you please clarify: what is the original size of the image, and how would you like to place it on a screen? Thanks and regards,

Comment: The original size of the image is 275*183, and i would like it to be in the center of the view( As you can see, the image is currently at the top left)

Comment: Did you choose Background, because you want have the image placed behind the rest of the Window UI?  You can accomplish the same look by using an image control and putting it at the back of the z-order.  See @AlexBell answer for one way to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accurately position the `Image` (or any other control) in `WPF` application, it's recommended to create a layout grid in `XAML`, and place content in a proper cell, which might be centered, or placed in any area (like in this example, where image appears in the right-bottom corner: http://www.shopdigit.com/Pericles-TTS-14-for-Win-TTS-14-01.htm).

The following sample code snippet demonstrates this technique:

```
<Window x:Class="YourClass.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="YourTitle"
        ShowInTaskbar="True"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <!-- main layout grid-->
    <Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                 <Image Margin="0,0,5,5" Source="[path to your image]" />
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,